# Proper way to setup a flag across entire site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple partial views that must be shown if a flag is set to `true` accross the entire site.

I have that flag hardcoded inside `appSettings` on my `web.config` file and is working nice. But now this flag must be set trough our back-end.

The site has a lot of traffic and I need a proper way to reach that, I feel like making a SQL request just to check this flag is an overkill.

I've though about reading a simple txt file containing the flag, but I dont know if it's still "too much".

How would be the most optimized way?

Comment: `But now this flag must be set trough our back-end.` what do you mean by that?

Comment: What I wanted to say is that this flag can't be hardcoded anymore. Someone else (our client, a non-developer) must be able to change that value without changing it on the `web.config` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `MemoryCache`. You can create a basic static class with a static property to return the cached flag value, and then you can define an absolute expiration to whatever comfort level you can live with (5 second or 60 minutes or any timespan) upon which you'd update the value in the cache.

Here is a very quick example to handle threading.

```
public static class CacheStore
{
    private static readonly string _keyMySharedFlag = "shared.flag";
    private static readonly object _lockMySharedFlag = new object();
    public static bool MySharedFlag
    {
        get
        {
            var cachedFlag = (bool?)MemoryCache.Default.Get(_keyMySharedFlag);
            if (cachedFlag != null)
                return cachedFlag.Value;
            lock (_lockMySharedFlag)
            {
                // Confirm no other threads wrote to cache while we waited
                cachedFlag = (bool?)MemoryCache.Default.Get(_keyMySharedFlag);
                if (cachedFlag != null)
                    return cachedFlag.Value;
                bool? newFlag = true; // Set to your database value
                var cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                cachePolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5); // 5 minutes
                MemoryCache.Default.Set(_keyMySharedFlag, newFlag, cachePolicy);
                return newFlag.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's running nice but it seems to last more than 5 minutes, in fact I waited for 20 minutes and the value was still the same until I refreshed the application pool and then it took the modified value. I have copied exactly the same code and I've set the `newFlag` value to my database driven value. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refreshing the app pool effectively clears the cache entirely. To debug your issue, I would change the cachePolicy expiration to `DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(1)`, then put a breakpoint on the first line of the `var cachedFlag` to step through the MemoryCache calls and see where the value is coming from. With that change, the existing value should be evicted from the cache almost immediately. Also, make sure you're not setting the "SlidingExpiration" instead of the "AbsoluteExpiration".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest define a global configuration class which has all the flags, common data in it and use Dependency Injection to inject it to where ever you need. This will result in a more testable solution I believe.